# Qatar is richest country but not largest economic country

Tags: economics

What is the difference between world largest economic countries and richest countries?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to know how the article/speaker defined richest, but in most articles I've seen they are using per-capita GDP. Qatar's per-person GDP is higher than other countries. Many of the small oil-producing countries are high on these lists. The GDP of Qatar is ~$150 billion, whereas the GDP of the United States is ~$19 trillion. The US is a much larger economy, but it also has far more people, so the per capita GDP is lower in the US than Qatar.

Comment: Indeed, we could reasonably ask whether Qatar actually has an economy, if (as was the case at one time) foreign companies do all the work of discovering & extracting the oil, and all the Qataris do is collect money.  It's the difference between working for a living, and living on an inheritance from your parents.

Comment: If interested, using World Bank figures (given when you put "_population of Qatar_" etc. in Google) you get: US: $18.57T / 323.4M = $57,977 (quoted: **$57,466**). Qatar: $152.5B / 2.57M = $59,338 (quoted: **$59,330**).  The first _per-capita-GDP_ figure is the one I calculated from the GDPs/populations; the second is the quoted per-capita-GDP. All figures are for 2016.